# Spring data JPA casting unsigned BITINT to Long instead of BigInteger

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, mysql-8.0

I have a unsigned bigint(20) column in my database table.

```
mysql driver version
8.0.14
```

My JPA entity looks like:

```
BigInteger columnName;
```

Problem is when I try to get data using the following select query:

```
select * from table where columnName in (large number [unsigned bigint])
```

I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: Value '13,224,435,352,132,323,241' is outside of valid range for type java.lang.Long
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:114)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:92)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getLong(ResultSetImpl.java:923)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getLong(ResultSetImpl.java:928)
```

So I saw the code for ResultSetImpl found this

```
case BIGINT:
    return Long.valueOf(getLong(columnIndex));

case BIGINT_UNSIGNED:
    return getBigInteger(columnIndex);
```

but it was still calling getLong() even though data type in table was unsigned bigint(20).

One way around which I see is to write a custom repository and do the parsing.

Wanted to ask have any of you faced this issue, If yes how have you gone about it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible to store the number (name?) as text?

Answer (score 0):

You have not presented your DDL (Data Definition Language) for your datatype, so I cannot be sure what your datatype in the database actually is actually. What you can do is cast it within your query using `cast()` function. So, your query would look like this:

```
select column, column, cast(bigint_unsigned_column as unsigned bigint), column
from table where columnName in (large number [unsigned bigint])
```

Comment: tried this. still getting the same ```Value '13,224,435,352,132,323,241' is outside of valid range for type java.lang.Long```

Answer (score 0):

Update: I solved this by using jdbcTemplate with rowMapper to cast the column in question to Biginteger/BigDecimal